# How to set slider to specific time frame, but allow user to extend it

Tags: powerbi

I would like to be able to have a slider on my PowerBI report which is set to the previous months range, but allow the user to extend this range if they want to.

I have a lookup table which has the previous years dates in. I am new to PowerBI so am unsure how to go about this.

At the moment the slider is defaulting as the min and max in the table. I want to have those as options, but when opening the report, the default is the previous month start and end date.

I am using the web based version and not the desktop version. I am unable to use the desktop version for this report.

This is what I am currently getting.
[image]

this is what I want it to look like, with the option to expand the slider to show a wider date range. 
[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what your current situation is and what you would like to achieve? Maybe add to screenshots of your current output, your model and your desired output. I think I might be able to help you out on this one.

Comment: Thanks, I have just updated my question with images.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want to change the default behaviour of the silcer in the web based PowerBI? I'm not too familiar with the web interface, but wouldn't saving the slicer in your prefered state cause it to load in that state the next time around?

Comment: Yes that's what I want. I want it to be dynamic though. So it shows the previous month.